# K in the Naming of Models and Techniques

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

Why is k chosen for the names k-nearest neighbors and k-fold cross validation? Is it arbitrary or just another mysterious naming?

Comment: I'm not sure but k is often used to represent an integer parameter in statistics (n as well, but n is often used to represent the size of the data). I don't think one should read too much into it, but maybe somebody knows better.